# Pass variables and access methods of User Control from CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have a function `renderWidget()` in *default.aspx.cs*. The idea of this is to add a User Control to a page.

```
public void renderWidget(string data) {
    Control ctrl = Page.LoadControl("/widgets/widget.ascx");
    dataPanel.Controls.Add(ctrl);
}
```

This all works fine, lovely jubbly. Now in the other end, at the User Control, I have the following code in *widget.ascx.cs*:

```
public class WidgetControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string testString = "";
    public void test() {
        Response.Write("test");
    }

}
```

The problem arises when I try to access either of the properties in the User Control. When I try to add `ctrl.test()` or `ctrl.testString = "test"` to default.aspx.cs, I get the error **"'System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'test'".** I feel like there's probably something very basic I'm missing here.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast to the correct type:

```
WidgetControl widget = (WidgetControl)ctrl;
widget.testString = "Foo";
widget.test();
```

[`LoadControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf.aspx) returns `Control` and not the actual type of your `UserControl`.

Comment: `The type or namespace name 'WidgetControl' could not be found.`I'm clearly being stupid here, and there's obviously a step I'm missing. Sorry for being idiotic.

Comment: @DeclanTyson: Look the the namespace of your UserControl, add the proper `using` at the top of your page or use the full namespace.

Comment: @Time Schmelter how do I find the namespace for the UserControl?

Comment: Left this for a bit, now come back to it and realised I made a typo in the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your instance to `WidgetControl`.

Comment: As with @Tim Schmelter - I get `The type or namespace name 'WidgetControl' could not be found`. I think I'm being a bit thick, but what am I doing wrong?